# CSVReader cannot read a line correctly

Tags: java, csv, string-formatting

I have a .csv file with 12 columns and read the file with CSVReader class.

```
List<String[]> rows = reader.readAll();
```

But I found some String[] have less than 12 elements. When I debugged, I found this is the CSV text format problem.

There are two problems:

1. Some columns end with backslash.

   For example, `"Column A content\", "Column B content"` will be read as one column as `\"` is seen as an escape character.
2. Some cells' contents have `\"` in them.

   For example, in one row, column A's content is a command line:
   `"d -R u+rwX \""${MYTMP}\"" > /dev/null 2>&1; rm -fr \""${MYTMP}\"" >"`

So I cannot think of a good replacement strategy to deal with this format problem.
(e.g replace all `\` with `\\`, this works for `"contentA\","contentB"` situation, but don't work for `\"` when it is the cell's content )

Any suggestions? Also welcome to discuss the bad formatting problems and solutions you experienced in CSV files so that Reader has problem reading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you replace `\",` with `\\",` that will solve your problem.
Most likely Unix command lines do not contain `,` character right after the `\"`. Yo may have to extend it with `\", "` to `\\", "` or maybe adding whitespaces.

A special case would be when your last column ends, so `\"<nl>` should be replaced to `\\"<nl>` where `<nl>` is whatever line delimiter you have (`\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try first to see whether this will cause other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one line like the next:

```
"Column A content\","Column B content","d -R u+rwX \""${MYTMP}\"" > /dev/null 2>&1; rm -fr \""${MYTMP}\"" >"
```

Try the next:

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser();
String line = "\"Column A content\\\",\"Column B content\",\"d -R u+rwX \\\"\"${MYTMP}\\\"\" > /dev/null 2>&1; rm -fr \\\"\"${MYTMP}\\\"\" >\"";
line = line.replaceAll("\\\\\"(?=,)", "\\\\\\\\\"");
line = line.replaceAll("\\\\\"\"", "\\\\\"");
String[] array = parser.parseLine(line);
for (String str : array) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
Column A content\
Column B content
d -R u+rwX "${MYTMP}" > /dev/null 2>&1; rm -fr "${MYTMP}" >
```